# Reading Input From Text File and print the salary and the name of employe

Tags: java, javascript

i need to Read input salary from user and then print the name and surname of employee
 (surname must be in upper case letters) that has salary more than a specified value using number format object  from the text File.
If entered salary is smaller than 100, Print message ‘’ the salary must be bigger than 100 “and if it’s bigger than the salaries in the file, print message “There is no employee has this salary.”

the text file name is employee.text contains name and surname of employee, City,
 department , salary and Date

Carl Johnson Paris Production 900 20/07/2000

Wiley Cyrus Istanbul Purchasing 800 21/05/2005

Harry Potter London Accounting 780 30/05/2001

Bruce Wayne  Gotham  Quality 450 05/08/2007

this is my code so far i am not getting output ?

```js
Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File("Employee.txt"));

NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter salary: ");
int salary = scan.nextInt();
if(salary < 100)
 System.out.println("The salary must be bigger than 100");
else 
 if(salary > 900)
{
      
 System.out.println("There is no employee has this salary.");
      
}
   
while(scanFile.hasNextInt())
{
 int sal = scanFile.nextInt();
 String code = scanFile.next();
 if(sal >= salary)
     System.out.println(code + fmt.format(sal));
   
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while you have to check for hasNextline() and not for hasNextInt():

```
while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
```

And in your int sal = scanFile.nextInt(); you´ll have find the int in the line - in this example you could do like this:

```
String nextLine = scanFile.nextLine();
int sal = Integer.parseInt(nextLine.substring(nextLine.lastIndexOf(" ")-3, nextLine.lastIndexOf(" ")));
```

But you will have to experiment so it works in all cases.